# Converting a PNG graph into tikz code

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg, inkscape

I'm a complete beginner in `LaTeX` and need to have this graph in tikz code for my work. I tried converting it to SVG with `Inkscape` and then to TikZ`enter code here` with `inkscape2tikz` but that didn't work, unfortunately.

Anyone know how I could manage this? I would appreciate any tips regarding, packages, tutorials etc. (I would like to actually learn how to do this, too :)).

Many thanks in advance.

[image: Graph I need in tikz code]

Comment: Welcome! It is not difficult to draw these graphs but a bit tedious. You may use the `shapes.geometric` or `graphdrawing` libraries. Very often these graphs do not pop out of thin air, so if there are some rules how to draw them you may be able to teach Ti*k*Z these rules and make generating the graphs much more efficient.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to recreate them by hand then.